# MS Access - select specific number of rows based on predefined condition with Macro

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access, while-loop

I need to create an Access macro that will pick a specific number of rows from one of my tables.

The macro will be run on a daily basis and this needs to pick a specific number of entries. For each entry in column 't1', it needs to only pick a specific numbers of rows from column 'Sample Size'. If there is no entry in the database, then skip and go to the next one.

My table is as follows:

[image]

I tried to use the below macro to define a number of the requested rows to pick and this seems to be successful. However, I cannot figure out how to link the first part with the other part of the script and how to modify it to only pick the required results through the loop (currently this is setup to pick top 25 but it only picks results from the first entry in my column - 'System ANGEast'. I guess I would need to use the While Wend statement but unsure how to use it in this scenario.

```
Sub DailyMacro()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim fld As Field
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strTableName As String

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM SampleF")

'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
rs.MoveFirst 
Do Until rs.EOF = True

    'Save contact name into a variable
    Top = rs!Final_Daily_Sample_Size
    t2 = rs!t1

    'Move to the next record. Don't ever forget to do this.
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
Else
MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
End If
   rs.Close 'Close the recordset
   Set rs = Nothing 'Clean up

'Create a new temporary table containing the required fields

strSQL = "SELECT [30 Days Sample].[Account], [30 Days Sample].[Name], [30 Days Sample].[Last Name], [30 Days Sample].[Activity Date], [30 Days Sample].[Type], [30 Days Sample].[Returns], [30 Days Sample].[Amount], [30 Days Sample].[t1] " & _
"INTO [temp_table]" & _
"FROM [30 Days Sample];"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

'Sort the data by the random number and move the top 25 into a new table

strTableName = "Final_Table" & Format(Date, "ddmmmyyyy")
strSQL = "SELECT TOP 25 [30 Days Sample].[Account], [30 Days Sample].[Name], [30 Days Sample].[Last Name], [30 Days Sample].[Activity Date], [30 Days Sample].[Type], [30 Days Sample].[Returns], [30 Days Sample].[Amount], [30 Days Sample].[t1] " & _
         "INTO " & strTableName & " " & _
         "FROM [temp_table]" & _
         "ORDER BY [temp_table].t1;"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, this code is VBA not a macro. Macros in Access are very different. Secondly, values in t1 are names of 30 tables? When you said "no entry in the database" you meant "table"? Instead of code creating temp table, this table should be permanent and records temporary. Use DELETE action to empty the table at beginning of process and INSERT SELECT action to populate.

Comment: Really don't see need for [temp_table] since it is just a duplicate of [30 Days Sample]. Not seeing purpose of recordset loop. The code just creates a single new table with only 25 records. If you want to populate 1 table with variable batches of TOP selected records based on dynamic criteria, use INSERT SELECT instead of SELECT INTO. What is table SampleF - the posted image? Really need to clarify what you are trying to accomplish.